# Prevenir pasar de fila al presionar enter en x-data-grid mui/material

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui

Tengo un [x-data-grid](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/) de [mui/material](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/) en modo editable, pero me gustaria que al actualizar una columna el foco se mantuviera en la misma fila. Alguien sabe si es posible?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Demo de material:
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://codesandbox.io/s/9gdz59?file=/Demo.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para conseguir tu objetivo podes hacer uso de las siguientes herramientas:

1. [`onCellEditStop`](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/#editing-events):

   > El usuario puede utilizar la propiedad onCellEditStop para comprobar la razón que disparó este evento. Por ejemplo, si la razón es `enterKeyDown` puede desactiva el comportamiento por defecto del evento.
2. [`apiRef.current.stopCellEditMode({ id, field })`](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/#stop-editing):

   > El usuario puede detener la edición de una celda llamando a este método y pasando el `id` de la fila y el `field` de la columna de la celda.

#### Ejemplo:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  GridColDef,
  GridRowsProp,
  DataGrid,
  GridCellEditStopParams,
  GridCellEditStopReasons,
  MuiEvent,
  useGridApiRef,
} from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import {
  randomCreatedDate,
  randomTraderName,
  randomUpdatedDate,
} from '@mui/x-data-grid-generator';

export default function DisableStopEditModeOnFocusOut() {

  const apiRef = useGridApiRef();

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 300, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        apiRef={apiRef}
        onCellEditStop={(params: GridCellEditStopParams, event: MuiEvent) => {
          if (params.reason === GridCellEditStopReasons.enterKeyDown) {
            event.defaultMuiPrevented = true;
            apiRef.current.stopCellEditMode({ id: params.id, field: params.field });
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  { field: 'name', headerName: 'Name', width: 180, editable: true },
  {
    field: 'age',
    headerName: 'Age',
    type: 'number',
    editable: true,
    align: 'left',
    headerAlign: 'left',
  },
  {
    field: 'dateCreated',
    headerName: 'Date Created',
    type: 'date',
    width: 180,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: 'lastLogin',
    headerName: 'Last Login',
    type: 'dateTime',
    width: 220,
    editable: true,
  },
];

const rows: GridRowsProp = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: randomTraderName(),
    age: 25,
    dateCreated: randomCreatedDate(),
    lastLogin: randomUpdatedDate(),
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: randomTraderName(),
    age: 36,
    dateCreated: randomCreatedDate(),
    lastLogin: randomUpdatedDate(),
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: randomTraderName(),
    age: 19,
    dateCreated: randomCreatedDate(),
    lastLogin: randomUpdatedDate(),
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: randomTraderName(),
    age: 28,
    dateCreated: randomCreatedDate(),
    lastLogin: randomUpdatedDate(),
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: randomTraderName(),
    age: 23,
    dateCreated: randomCreatedDate(),
    lastLogin: randomUpdatedDate(),
  },
];
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-hopper-cs3mfq?file=/Demo.tsx)</kbd>

---

#### Actualización: caso `editMode="row"`

> Eventos de edición:
> Las interacciones que se inician y detienen activan los eventos 'cellEditStart' y 'cellEditStop', respectivamente. Para la edición de filas, los eventos son "rowEditStart" y "rowEditStop".

En el caso que se configure el `DataGrid` con [`editMode="row"`](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/#row-editing), deberíamos utilizar:

- [`onRowEditStop`](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/#editing-events) en lugar de `onCellEditStop`
- [`apiRef.current.stopRowEditMode({ id });`](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/#stop-editing) en lugar de `stopCellEditMode`

<kbd>[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-aj-2kw79n?file=/Demo.tsx)</kbd>

Comment: que pasa si tengo `editMode="row"` al parecer ya no funciona

Comment: Hola @DoubleM. Logicamente no va a funcionar porque en ese caso debería usar `onRowEditStop` y `apiRef.current.stopRowEditMode`